# INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... statement not working

Tags: mysql, c, mariadb

I'm having some trouble with an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement that I don't quite understand.  I'm not sure if it's an issue with MariaDB or something I'm doing wrong.

I have a table (which we'll call `table_a`), which consists of columns `id`, `c`, and `b`.  `c` and `b` are not unique, but I have an index set up on `c`.

I have another table (which we'll call `table_b`), which consists of columns `table_a_id_1`, `table_a_id_1`.  I use this table to track rows in `table_a` that have the same values of `c` as each other -- i.e., if rows 1-4 all have the same value of `c`, then there would be 6 entries in `table_b` -- `1, 2`, `1, 3`, `1, 4`, `2, 3`, `2, 4`, and `3, 4`.

So, here's the idea -- I add a bunch of rows into `table_a`.  After each one, I grab the insert ID, store it in `insert_id`, then prepare a statement with the following query:

`INSERT INTO table_b (table_a_id_1, table_a_id_2) SELECT ?, id FROM table_a WHERE c = ? AND id != ?`

I then bind `insert_id`, the value of `c` that I just inserted into `table_a`, and `insert_id` (again) to the statement and execute it.

Here's my problem: the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` query doesn't do anything.  It doesn't cause any errors -- it just doesn't insert anything.  But, if I grab the values of `insert_id` and `c` and run the query through PHPMyAdmin, it works just fine.  I'm not using transactions in this program...so I'm honestly confused as to why it works when I'm doing it manually versus doing it programmatically.

Anyone have any ideas why it's doing this?

**EDIT:** I changed my program so that I do separate `SELECT` and `INSERT` queries.  In my program, the `SELECT` query isn't turning up any rows, even though I can see them if I run the exact same query in something like PHPMyAdmin.  I'm really confused here.

**EDIT 2:** Here's my code (some of the error handling code removed for brevity):

```
int save_to_database(char *b, char *c, my_ulonglong &insert_id) {
  const char *insert_str = "INSERT INTO table_a (c, b) VALUES (?, ?)";
  MYSQL_STMT *stmt;
  MYSQL_BIND bind[2];
  int retval;
  unsigned long buffer_length[2];
  my_bool is_null[2];

  stmt = mysql_stmt_init(boinc_db.mysql);
  if(!stmt) {
    // Print an error, return -1
  }

  retval = mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, insert_str, strlen(insert_str));
  if(retval) {
    // Print an error, close stmt, return -1
  }

  memset(bind, 0, sizeof(bind));

  buffer_length[0] = strlen(c);
  buffer_length[1] = strlen(b);

  is_null[0] = 0;
  is_null[1] = 0;

  bind[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
  bind[0].buffer = c;
  bind[0].buffer_length = buffer_length[0];
  bind[0].length = &buffer_length[0];
  bind[0].is_null = &is_null[0];
  bind[0].is_unsigned = 0;

  bind[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
  bind[1].buffer = b;
  bind[1].buffer_length = buffer_length[1];
  bind[1].length = &buffer_length[1];
  bind[1].is_null = &is_null[1];
  bind[1].is_unsigned = 0;

  if(mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, bind)) {
    // Print an error, close stmt, return -1
  }

  if(mysql_stmt_execute(stmt)) {
    // Print an error, close stmt, return -1
  }

  insert_id = mysql_stmt_insert_id(stmt);

  mysql_stmt_close(stmt);
  return 0;
}

int generate_matches(my_ulonglong pair_id, char *c) {
  const char *insert_str = "INSERT INTO table_b (a_pair, b_pair) SELECT ?, id FROM table_a WHERE c = ? AND id != ?";

  MYSQL_STMT *stmt;
  MYSQL_BIND in_bind[3];
  int retval;
  unsigned long in_buffer_len[3];
  my_bool in_is_null[3];

  stmt = mysql_stmt_init(boinc_db.mysql);
  if(!stmt) {
    // Print an error, return -1
  }

  retval = mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, insert_str, strlen(insert_str));
  if(retval) {
    // Print an error, close stmt, return -1
  }

  memset(in_bind, 0, sizeof(in_bind));

  in_buffer_len[0] = sizeof(pair_id);
  in_is_null[0] = 0;

  in_buffer_len[1] = strlen(c) + 1;
  in_is_null[1] = 0;

  in_buffer_len[2] = sizeof(pair_id);
  in_is_null[2] = 0;

  in_bind[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG;
  in_bind[0].buffer = (void *) &pair_id;
  in_bind[0].buffer_length = in_buffer_len[0];
  in_bind[0].length = &in_buffer_len[0];
  in_bind[0].is_null = &in_is_null[0];
  in_bind[0].is_unsigned = 1;

  in_bind[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
  in_bind[1].buffer = (void *) c;
  in_bind[1].buffer_length = in_buffer_len[1];
  in_bind[1].length = &in_buffer_len[1];
  in_bind[1].is_null = &in_is_null[1];
  in_bind[1].is_unsigned = 0;

  in_bind[2].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG;
  in_bind[2].buffer = (void *) &pair_id;
  in_bind[2].buffer_length = in_buffer_len[2];
  in_bind[2].length = &in_buffer_len[2];
  in_bind[2].is_null = &in_is_null[2];
  in_bind[2].is_unsigned = 1;

  if(mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, in_bind)) {
    // Print an error, close stmt, return -1
  }

  if(mysql_stmt_execute(stmt)) {
    // Print an error, close stmt, return -1
  }

  mysql_stmt_close(stmt);

  return 0;
}
```

Later on in the program, I have:

```
  if(save_to_database(b, c, insert_id)) {
    // Throw an error and exit
  }

  if(generate_matches(insert_id, c)) {
    // Throw an error and exit
  }
```

And I can see in my database that there should be instances of this happening:

```
MariaDB [database]> SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE c = "1000140625" AND id != 27803;
+-------+------------+-----------+
| id    | c          | b         |
+-------+------------+-----------+
| 27801 | 1000140625 | 537675600 |
| 27802 | 1000140625 | 659036664 |
+-------+------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My log files show no errors were thrown, and yet there are no records in `table_b`.

Comment: Are you certain that the `SELECT` returns any records?

Comment: Yes -- if I take the `SELECT` part of the query and run it by itself, it returns records.  What I haven't done is to try to do that in my program (instead of using the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement).

Comment: Which DB you use ? you mention both Mysql and mariadb

Comment: It's MariaDB.  The client library is MySQL's client library, but the database itself is MariaDB.

Comment: You can check the general query log if it is enabled. check whether query is executing or not.

Comment: It's not, and at the rate I'm running queries, I'd be afraid to turn it on.

Comment: Can you share the code where you perform this INSERT....SELECT? If your SELECT works fine in phpmyadmin but not in your code, then I'm betting that's where the issue is.

Comment: What happens when you remove the "" around the Where c ="1000140625" I am wondering if you are calling a string instead of an iteger

Comment: It would cause an error, because `c` and `b` are both `varchar(255)`'s.  (Essentially, I'm doing math with very large numbers...so I can't store them as integers.)

Comment: @MattCole - I have no desire to wade through 50 lines of code to figure out what is in `stmt`.  Can you show us the SQL after the binding??  And you say the query is not executing??  Then it is not a MySQL problem??

Comment: How big are your numbers?  Would `DECIMAL(64,0)` suffice?